# How to drop column from a pandas dataframe if it has a missing value after a specified row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with hundreds of columns and would like to drop a column if it contains any missing values after row `n`. How can this be done? Thanks

Comment: plz provide [mre]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your index is 0-based and contiguous, you could just check for any `na` values after row `n` in each column and drop them if so:

```
out = df.drop(
    columns = [c for c in df.columns if df.loc[n:, c].isna().any()]
)
```

If the index is not 0-based, or not contiguous, you can use `iloc` instead, but need to get the column number instead of name for testing:

```
out = df.drop(
    columns = [c for i, c in enumerate(df.columns) if df.iloc[n:, i].isna().any()]
)
```

Note I've assumed your missing values are `NaN`, if they are for example `''` (empty string), you can do something like this:

```
out = df.drop(
    columns = [c for c in df.columns if (df.loc[n:, c].astype(str) == '').any()]
)
```